# Subtype polymorphism components

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am just starting out with java. Just tying to make sure I can explain this correctly and understand the terminology. It looks like subtype polymorphism will consist of two components, polymorphic objects and polymorphic methods.

**MY QUESTION**
So `Animal a = new Dog();` Would "a" be the polymorphic object and method overriding be the polymorphic methods?

Comment: Dog() is a constructor and rest is polymorphic call , try search , this is surely a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Polymorphism** is a feature of a programming language that allows routines to use variables of different types. Some piece of code is polymorphic if it can use some different types at the same time. *The more polymorphic code the better*.

There are two types of polymorphism - **universal** and **ad hoc**:

1. Under the universal polymorphism one type may use infinite other types (*e.g. `toString()` method works with any reference type*);
2. Under ad hoc polymorphism the quantity of types it works with is known in advance (*e.g. `f(int)` can be used with `int`, `byte`, `short` and `char`*).

There are three types of **ad hoc** polymorphism:

1. **Widening Primitive Conversions** (*e.g. method that accepts `double` can also accept any of 7 primitives*);
2. **Operator Overloading** (in Java there is no operator overloading by user, in other languages there it is, *e.g. `+` sign can be overloaded*);
3. **Overloading** is a feature that allows a class to have more than one methods with the same name, if their argument lists are different.

And there are two **universal** polymorphism types – Parametric Polymorphism and Subtype Polymorphism:

1. **Parametric Polymorphism** (aka **Generics**) is a class with underdetermined type (`T` or `E` character that can be replaced with any type).
2. **Subtype Polymorphism** – is that we have because of **inheritance** (When we inherit from some class, in the method signature it is possible to write superclass and put there *any subclass*). This subtype mechanism doesn't work without **virtual methods**.

All the static methods are *non virtual* and all non-static methods are *virtual*.

**Virtual method** – is a method of a class, that can be overridden in subclasses in the way that concrete method implementation for the method call will be defined in *runtime*. Then it is not necessary for developer to know the exact type of an object for working with it with virtual methods: it's enough to know that object is an instance of class or subclass of class, where this method is declared.

Virtual methods is very important way of polymorphism implementation. They allow to create a *generic code* that can be applied to base class as well as to objects of his any subclass. At the same time base class defines the way of coordinating with objects, and any of its descendants can have concrete implementation of this way.

Polymorphism can also be reached by using inheritance, because if we have parent class and child class and we have a code for parent class, then we can use it with child class as well (*e.g. method that accept `java.lang.Object` can accept any other type*).

---

An object which can be manipulated by using virtual function is called **polymorphic object**.

And method overriding is not considered as polymorphism. Signature **polymorphic method** is one which can operate with any of a wide range of call signatures and return types.

This is a great example of polymorphism:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

In your example `a` is a reference of type `Animal` to the object of type `Dog`.

The *compiler* checks the **left part** of the expression and *JVM works* on the basis of **right part**.

Comment: So this (Animal a = new Dog();) along with method overriding are both considered subtype polymorphism. It seems there are two components to it. So I was asking if object "a" would be  called object polymorphism and if method overriding would be called polymorphic methods?

Comment: No it is not the same, please read my answer, I updated it completely.

Comment: I have read a lot of different post that say method overriding is polymorphism. In Overriding, we use the same method name and signature, and the method is able to respond to the objects in different ways depending on the objects type. So why is overriding not also considered polymorphism? Wouldn't these both be subtype polymorphism?

Comment: you are right, in overriding we define method with the same name and signature to change the method's behavior and this is ad-hoc type of polymorphism. And polymorphism is a much wider concept that consists this and other different types. So it is not right to say that overriding alone is polymorphism. It is more than that.